# catcodes vs. autonum

Tags: equations, catcodes, autonum

I'm trying to make certain equations with large amounts of special characters more readable by playing with catcodes.

This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

$$
\catcode`X\active
\defX{\times}
X
$$

\begin{equation}
\catcode`X\active
\defX{\times}
X
\end{equation}

\[
\catcode`X\active
\defX{\times}
X
\]

\end{document}
```

But when I `\usepackage{autonum}`, the third option (`\[\]`) breaks with "Undefined control sequence". Is there a way around this other that always going for the second option?

[MiKTeX 1/31/2014]

EDIT: in the actual document, I am switching catcodes only for specific parts of equations by using custom environments inside the latter. So while redefining catcodes outside an equation could be made to work, this question is more about how to do this without turning equations inside out.

Comment: for whatever unknown reason, using tex live 2012, this doesn't fail with an error, but no number is produced for the `equation` example.  the relevant version numbers are: `autonum`, 2012/05/26 v0.1; `book.cls`, 2007/10/19 v1.4h.

Comment: You should always say what control sequence is undefined. I suspect `\defX` and, if that is the case, it would very much help identify the cause of the problem: `autonum` must redefine `\[...\]` so that it takes its contents as an argument.

Comment: @barbara: I'd guess that in that version, `\[\]` was not implemented as a single-argument macro, then. The lack of `equation` number is, actually, (part of) what `autonum` does: it removes numbers from unreferenced equations.

Comment: @Dan: It appears to be `defX`, yes. I'd be happy for `autonum` to be fixed, but (a) this does not give a solution right now, and (b) it turns out there are similar problems with `align` and other `amsmath` environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the character active, you can make it math active.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{autonum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\activate}{mO{0}m}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\newcommand~}[#2]{#3}%
  \mathcode`#1="8000
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\activate{X}{\times}
X
\end{equation}

\[
\activate{X}{\times}
X
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even say

```
\begin{equation}
\activate{X}[1]{\times_{#1}}
X{3}
\end{equation}
```

You can imagine better applications.

Comment: There's some magic going on here, but I think I understand how it works. One side question: why `\relax`?

Comment: @vpozdyayev `\relax` is just for safety; it's not really necessary, as TeX gobbles a space after a numeric constant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an EDIT based on OP comment.  In this case, I still assign the new catcode in advance of the `\[ \]` structure, but demonstrate that I can reassign it to something else within the `\[ \]` structure.  Does that assist the OP better?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{autonum}
\catcode`X\active
\def\xact{\catcode`X\active\defX{\times}}
\def\xnormA{\defX{A}\catcode`X11}
\def\xnormX{\defX{\char88}\catcode`X11}
\catcode`X11
\begin{document}

$$
\xact
X
$$

\begin{equation}
\xact
X
\end{equation}

{\xact
\[
X \textrm{~becomes~} \xnormA  X \textrm{~becomes~} \xnormX  X
\textrm{~becomes~} \xact  X
\]
}
\centering X returns as normal
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's one way to do it, thank you. But it looks like I've shortened the code sample too much. See the question update.

Comment: @vpozdyayev And another revision to be able to return it to `X`

Comment: Upvoting, since this answer helped me understand what's going on. However, the issue of "turning equations inside out" (as in: having to provide information on equation contents before the equation itself) still bothers me here. In the end, I went the `\scantokens` route.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: for equations, egreg's solution appears to be the most appropriate one. I'm leaving the old solution here as an alternative that might be useful in a more general context (like changing catcodes in macro arguments and tricky environments).

---

For the record, the solution I have ended up with is essentially an (un?)healthy dose of `\scantokens`es inside `\[\]` and some alternative math environments:

```
\let\oldEquationBracket\[
\def\[#1\]{\oldEquationBracket\scantokens{#1}\]}

\def\xalignImpl#1{\begin{align}\scantokens{#1}\end{align}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xalign}{\collect@body\xalignImpl}{}
\makeatother

...
```

(tips on how to put it into `align` itself instead of defining a new environment will be appreciated). This solution may or may not have hidden issues, but it appears to work for my use cases.